# Could multiple ajax calls be made from multiple buttons on a jsp page, with JSR 303 validation in SPring MVC 4 working?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring mvc 4 and jquery, I have to create a project for my school in which there is a jsp [Screenshot of JSP Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QnraX.png) page as shown in the attached picture

In the jsp page there two sets of textarea in two different rows, when user enters some data in 'DataSet1 textArea' and clicks on 'Process1' button then an ajax call is made to the controller and model is updated to show result in ResultSet1 textarea, same should happen in the row below(could a new ajax call be made here without interfering textAreas of row 1?). My question is what design approach is best suited in this case?

I am sharing my code and problems that I am facing with current design approach that I am taking:
Here is my controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/tokenizer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String goTokenize(Model model) {
    TokenData data = new TokenData();
    model.addAttribute("tokenData", data);
    return "tokenizer";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/tokenizer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String setTokenize(@Valid @ModelAttribute TokenData tokenData, Errors errors) {
    if (errors.hasErrors()) {
        return "tokenizer";
    }
    return "tokenizer";
}
```

Here is my js code with which I am capturing click of button

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  //For button Process
  $('#json').click(function(event) {
   $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : 'tokenizer',
    data : JSON.stringify($("#textarea").val()),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {
     $('#result').html(result.text);
    },
    error : function(e) {
     console.log('Error: ' + e)
     alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
   });
  });
  //For button Process2
  $('#json1').click(function(event) {
   
  $.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    contentType : "application/json",
    url : 'tokenizer',
    data : JSON.stringify($("#textareanew").val()),
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {
     console.log("success--"+result)
     $('#textarea').val(result.text);
    },
    error : function(e) {
     console.log('Error: ' + e)
     alert('Error: ' + e);
    }
   });
  });
 });
</script>
```

Here is my model Object

```
public class TokenData {

@NotEmpty
private String tokenData;
private String resultData;

@NotEmpty
private String tokenDataNew;
public String getTokenDataNew() {
    return tokenDataNew;
}

public void setTokenDataNew(String tokenDataNew) {
    this.tokenDataNew = tokenDataNew;
}

public String getResultDataNew() {
    return resultDataNew;
}

public void setResultDataNew(String resultDataNew) {
    this.resultDataNew = resultDataNew;
}

private String resultDataNew;

public String getResultData() {
    return resultData;
}

public void setResultData(String resultData) {
    this.resultData = resultData;
}

public String getTokenData() {
    return tokenData;
}

public void setTokenData(String tokenData) {
    this.tokenData = tokenData;
}
```

Problems I am facing are

1. I am using spring form tag in jsp page  below is the code snippet,

```html
form:form modelAttribute="tokenData" id="formx" action="${formxyz}">
```

if i don't use form tag in jsp, then databinding and validation(jsr 303) do not work

2.SInce I am using form tag, hence when i click buttons(which are of 'submit' type as 'button' type do not work with data binding) then when i click on any buttonthe whole form data oes to controller and validation as well as other processing occurs for all form fields.

My question is, is there any way by which I can make multiple ajax calls from multiple buttons on jsp page, with JSR 303 validation working?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell, Javascript cannot invoke any functions of JSP.

JSR 303 validation, however, is done by Hibernate validator (this is an implementation of JSR 303) at controller level, not by JSP.

So the answer is YES. You can just remove type='submit' from your buttons in order to prevent form submit, and let AJAX do post data to your controller.
The JSR 303 will be done by your controller.

For your "null" data question:
First, please check your "data" field in your AJAX call. The data must be in JSON format with exactly same structure of your TokenData. 
Second, if you want your controller return data rather than ModelAndView, you should annotate with `@ResponseBody` at method level, or `@RestController` at class level.

For more information, please read: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html

Comment: If I use _button type="button"_ in place of _button type="submit"_ then on clicking the button my controller receives null data. If I use _button type="submit"_ then only my controller is receiving the data, could you please guide here. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, using ResponsEntity,RequestBody,ResponseBody and Valid annotations now my code is working. I'm marking your inputs as the answer.

Comment: Glade to see that